# $.alert is not a function in Jquery in console error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm executing an alert with Jquery as like `$.alert(param);` The console is providing as $.alert is not a function.
How to overcome it ?

```
function AlertModelPoupMast(param) {

        $.alert(param);  //It's custom alert. dont suggest normal alert() here please.

        return false;
    }
```

If I place `$.noConflicts()` it is working for first time , but after that again not working.

```
function AlertModelPoupMast(param) {
        $.noConflict();   //working for 1 time. not working from 2nd time.
        $.alert(param);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: we are using some custom alert from there. So if I place normal alert it's coming. no problem. But I need to work with this way only. which is worked previously.

Comment: `jQuery.alert` is not a jQuery function its simple javascript function without need to use jQuery. If its custom alert, then post that custom alert function code!

Comment: It has to be pretty darn custom to not even be defined ?

Comment: I think, OP has some kind of different problem here... :-)

Comment: use that damn console man

Comment: @madalin ivascu , At which point I need use console ?

Comment: @madalin ivascu I'm asking you at which point you got doubt ? I used console. That's the reason i found the issue error as "$.alert is not a function". Without using consolem How could I get it ?

Comment: visually inspecting it , can you provide a link to your $.alert library?,did you append the library to your page correctly , have you got and 404 in the resource tab?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$.alert();
```

to

```
alert();
```

Comment: As OP said: It's custom alert. dont suggest normal alert() here please.

Comment: I am still waiting for it to be added by OP.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you not included jquery file or $ is conflicted with some other plugin, changing $ with Jquery may solve that problem,
I think you are using craftpip custom alert [like here](https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm)

here you look with the issue

https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

me also faced similar issue. And the issue was `jquery.min.js` loaded twice which caused conflict. Make sure jquery and all other js files loaded once. It may fix the problem. Also put `jquery.min.js` at the top of other js files if possible, because jquery plugin may be needed by other plugins.

Hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Use

alert("Your message");

Please ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: As OP said: It's custom alert. dont suggest normal alert() here please.